# Why does Thunderbird label the Trash folder as "Deleted"

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I'm running Thunderbird 3.1.10 (British version) and I'm having this annoying problem where IMAP Trash folders - named "Trash" on the server - are being labelled as "Deleted" in Thunderbird. It's not critical but highly annoying as I would prefer to have the folder in Thunderbird named the same as it is on the server.

Does anyone know why this happens, and more importantly, how it can be disabled?

---

Note that the problem I am having is there's a disconnect between the client side labelling of the folder and what it's referred to on the server. I have already tried using the Thunderbird about:config box and changing the name used but it didn't solve it.

Here is an image of what I mean.

[image: Thunderbird Folder properties]

Comment: Have you tried setting it as US English?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP_Trash_folder). It gives you an explanation and a solution to your problem much better than I could explain it here.

Comment: Thunderbird is not creating a folder on the server named "Deleted" it's using the server's Trash folder, just labelling it as "Deleted" on the client side. I can't rename it in the folder properties because it considers Trash to be a reserved name.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)